# What does "put on a show" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is verse one of the song *Moves Like Jagger* by Maroon 5 (sorry it looks so spread out I tried to single line it, but didn't work):

> Just shoot for the stars
>   If it feels right
>   Then aim for my heart
>   If you feel like
>   And take me away, make it okay
>   I swear I'll behave
>   You wanted control
>   So we waited
>   **I put on a show**
>   Now we're naked
>   You say I'm a kid
>   My ego is big
>   I don't give a shit
>   And it goes like this

In line 9-10, "I put on a show. Now we're naked", what does *putting on a show* mean?

Comment: Maybe a striptease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levine's verse implies that he put on a pretense of honoring his partner's wishes to take advantage of her. It's related to this meaning of [*show*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/show%5Bnoun%5D):

> an outward and often exaggerated indication of something abstract (as a feeling) for effect
>
> **Related Words** act, charade, facade (*also* façade), front, guise, pretense (*or* pretence), put-on, semblance, simulation; affectation, pose, sham; betrayal, disclosure